# Change submit form after two 'select' options

Tags: jquery

I have a simple web structure like this:

- First: there is the first 'select' option
- Second: a 'select' option again, but will differ by the option selected by the first 'select' (I use .change of JQuery to implement it).

I got a problem to implement below,

Third: Depending on the second option, I'll give users a 'form' to submit their query which may including one or two 'input'.

Can I use jQuery again to do it? I tried '.change' again, but not working.

Thanks in advance

Yang

Comment: without showing your code how one can answer to your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('#select1').on('change',function(){
   // fill second drop down select options
});

$('#select2').on('change',function(){
    if($('#select1').val()!="" && $(this).val()!="")
    {
        $('form').submit(); 
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please select options");
    }       
});
```

Comment: I tried to use $('form').html to change the format in 'form', but not working. Can I use it in this way?

Comment: Yes, I'm very close. I found an editing error in my code. I'm trying to put two 'input' in the form.

Comment: Thanks. It's been fixed. I'm very new for JQuery. After fixing several syntax buy in calling, everything is fine now. Thanks.